# Why do we have a daily limit of 200 reputation?

Tags: discussion

Obviously I don't run into this limit too often, but I'm disappointed when I do. What is the reasoning behind having a daily limit of 200 reputation?

Comment: Because it's a very badly designed system overall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's just there to provide a throttle for reputation gain, which has a few small benefits (beyond the obvious of helping curtail abuse). I don't necessarily believe these to be true (I think it's mostly just an abuse throttle), but they're interesting to think about:

First, it means that a user with higher reputation has perforce earned that reputation over a span of days, visiting the site over several days and actively participating during that time. Second, it helps enforce the idea that reputation (and consequently, things you do to earn reputation) isn't the sole focus of the site, that there are other ways to participate which don't necessarily result in reputation gain (but might have badges associated with them, or no "reward" at all).

Comment: +1 I believe the main focus is to build that continual relationship with the site. Making users more nested in the community and help develop and help others over a course of an extended time frame not just one day that someone went around answering questions.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's to stop people to take unfair advantage using their friends, so that they can make it to leaderboard in less than two days.
You won't want a newbie to have thousands of rep per day ;)

Comment: That's a good point. It prevents abuse

Comment: Who has that many friends? :)

Comment: I thought that's what the 15 rep to up-vote was for?

Comment: @JoshPetrie I got 500+ frnds in facebook, thanks to MafiaWars. They can do anything for free weapons :p